# How to test this URL is correct after encryption?

Tags: manual-testing, api-testing

On the administrator side of a system I have a means of adding a module, each module has its own application path and a the possibility of being a *subscription*.  In short if subscription is true, it will amend the launching URL of the module to add &subType=x (x is whatever I set when enabling the subscription I get another field to populate).  Now when I launch this module on the user-side of the system, how can I confirm that this subtype has accurately been added to the call?

Sounds simple enough, however the URL on the user side is heavily encrypted e.g

> LaunchModule.aspx?enc=tmdyDHtFOFV+MCM8I+kcM+dInz3KzImy74LEYcjBz6HkVrDPPnNNdqE3sYLnHUINpwcaQFViPxdC3Am3Do5oXh7Lm2/P9OXNifHgSNHf7hIwRT/x7vGSN5qDfiYHg9l7MzOFxJwgo0NRvrBdB+3RPO3nO2XQKM87zcAldMdE7fV9Eleg03MXIZVEBw+orqSeNxEcv1aVMl4QERibuYSI8O7guSiZAJyUseIVTlPIym/IVNvU/aSiCh8nCh53hd3LZYqUvdWsM7WpfHgn2ZpKXuhcCNjQwJdTEmWyfn/X/nQVTxKgurLiV8UPkV0SeLsA

How can I confirm when one is adding the subType paramater properly? can I use chrome dev console somehow?  It's not possible for me to decrypt the url here.

I've tried doing the same setup hoping the encryption would match so I could just add/remove the subscription and the encrypted string would change somewhat, however it seems very heavily randomised each time

Also worth noting, I don't have a means to pass in a valid subType to see something on screen, this is entirely used by a third party and I have no idea what they will use it for or even access to their network if I did.

Answer (score 1):

Test behaviour not implementation.

> how can I confirm that this subtype has accurately been added to the
>   call?

What would this subtype have for an effect on the user of this system? Validate the end-result has happend, not that the subtype has been added.

- Arrange: Setup the system with data to verify something
- Act: Take steps to act the thing you want to test
- Assert: Assert the end-result is what you expected.

Maybe you can give a better example how you are stuck with testing the full flow?

Comment: I am unable to validate the end-result in this instance as we have nothing that utilises it in the realm of our network

Comment: Doesn't that mean you need a test-environment infrastructure setup where you can validate it? That seems part of the arrange, make your setup testable, even if that means installing softwares your API users would use that is out of your control. If you are stuck maybe spar with the developers and business owners how you could make it testable for you.